# Excel Show Multiple Matches with 2 Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I need a formula which will find me all names matching two criteria in an Excel table.

Criteria 1 is a date, criteria 2 is a status (Approved or Denied).

What formula can I place in cells P4, P5, and P6 for Excel to show me, in order, the names of the staff who have requested 9/30/19 off and have a status of "Approved"? Ideally this could show up to 10 names per date/approved combo search.
[Here is a photo of my data table with headers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQZ1.jpg)

This formula works, but finds all results only matching the date, it does not allow me to consider the status of Approved.

```
=INDEX($J$3:$J$402,AGGREGATE(15,3,(('Data Entry'!$D$3:$D$402=$N$4)/('Data Entry'!$D$3:$D$402=$N$4)*ROW($D$3:$D$402))-ROW($D$2),ROWS(M$4:M4)))
```

Can the "Approved" variable be added?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like a filter your data would be simpler than formulas, click on those little down arrows and filter away...

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula.

```
=index(J:J, aggregate(15, 7, row($3:$402)/((D$3:D$402=N$4)*(H$3:H$402=O$4)), row(1:1)))
```

Fill down for 2nd, 3rd, etc. Wrap in IFERROR to show zero-length string instaed of error.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

*This array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($J$3:$J$11, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($N$4, $D$3:$D$11)*COUNTIF($O$4, $H$3:$H$11), ROW($J$3:$J$11)-MIN(ROW($J$3:$J$11))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- Enter formula in Cell `P4`, & finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** then fill down.
- Cell `N4` & `O4` contains `Day Off` and `Status`, works as variable, *you may replace them with fixed values also*.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @user1095209 ,, if you wish then you may accept it as Answer as well Up vote also,, keep asking ☺