# Alternative IF/AND arguments in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to use INDEX - MATCH to pull up a variable in column A under two different conditions.   I will put the exact statement here in a moment, but for simplification, the concept is simply this: in a sports event, one team will be listed as the home team and one team will be listed as the away team.  If "team" equals "home team" and "opponent" equals "away team," I want to pull the game ID number that matches that pair from column A.  But in addition, I ALSO want this to hapen if "team" equals "away team," and opponent equals "home team." I can write a successful formula to pull the game ID in either of the two conditions, but when I try to combine them so it does it in the case of a match either way, it succeeds for 1/2 of the dataset and fails for the other 1/2 (giving a #N/A error).

Hope that helps.  But here's the formula I'm trying to make work (for reference, Column A = gameID; Column F = away_team, Column G = home_team):

```
=IF(AND(MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!G:G, 0), (MATCH([@Opponent],'Master Game'!F:F, 0))), INDEX('Master Game'!A:A, MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!G:G,0)))
```

I have also tried:

```
=IFS(AND(MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!G:G, 0), (MATCH([@Opponent],'Master Game'!F:F, 0))), INDEX('Master Game'!A:A, MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!G:G,0)), AND(MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!F:F, 0), (MATCH([@Opponent],'Master Game'!G:G, 0))),  INDEX('Master Game'!A:A, MATCH([@team],'Master Game'!F:F, 0)))
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: A non-MATCH throws an error and everything stops there. You need something like `=IF(AND(ISUMBER(MATCH(..., ..., 0)), ISUMBER(MATCH(..., ..., 0))), <if true>, <if false>)` but more likely you need a two column MATCH. See [Excel Show Multiple Matches with 2 Criteria](https://superuser.com/questions/1487081).

Comment: Your question has insufficient info so that it's not clear waht combination you are trying so far, so  please [Edit] your post & add some sample data along with expected results, help us to fix it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, this solved it, FWIW:

```
=IF([@[Home or Away?]]="AWAY", INDEX('Master Game'!A:A, MATCH([@team]&[@Opponent],'Master Game'!F:F&'Master Game'!G:G,0)), INDEX('Master Game'!A:A, MATCH([@team]&[@Opponent],'Master Game'!G:G&'Master Game'!F:F,0)))
```